# Inserting an array into an other array

Tags: php, arrays

I ask this question because i didn't find any kind of array function which could replace some elements of an array with elements in an other array.

I want to replace the old elements starting at a specific position, not the beginning.

Comment: what you have tried? Give some example what you are expecting

Comment: You can loop through your array and change values

Comment: `$newarr['whatever'] = $oldarr['somethingelse']`. It's not rocket science...

Comment: well, i want a string to be in an array, but not in one string, but with single characters. and i want to overwrite the pervious elements. so i split the string, sort it into an array, but i don't know how to insert them into the old array, replacing from $array[x] to $array[y] items.

Comment: i can't add code, because it's too complicated to indicate this specific problem

Comment: @MarcB seriously? i said i want to begin it from a specific position, not dumping the previous array

Comment: @Ibu   yes, that would be a good solving. but i hoped there would be an other, easier way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use 
[array_splice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) function

For example:

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 2, 1, array("black", "maroon"));
// $input is now array("red", "green","black", "maroon")
```

Example with two dimension array:

```
<?php
$input = array(
    array(1,2,3),
    array(4,5,6),
    array(7,8,9),
    array(10,11,12)
);

$replacement = array(
    array(13,14,15),
    array(16,17,18)
);

$start = 2;
$count = count($input)-$start;

array_splice($input, $start, $count, $replacement);

var_dump($input);
```

[See result](http://codepad.org/Rf06US5n)

Comment: the old array is a two dimensional array. sorry i forgot to mention that.

Comment: `<?php
    $input = array(
    array(1,2,3),
    array(4,5,6),
    array(7,8,9),
    array(10,11,12)
);

$replacement = array(
    array(13,14,15),
    array(16,17,18)
);

$start = 2;
$count = count($input)-$start;
array_splice($input, $start, $count, $replacement);

var_dump($input);`

Comment: Interesting! I will try this, thanks.